# Is it possible to customize the skin on Zeppelin?

Tags: apache-zeppelin

Is it possible to customize the skin on Zeppelin?  In otherwords, replace the Zeppelin logo with something else?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it is possible very much.

As you know Apache Zeppelin (incubating) is an open source project, so need just to:

- clone it from [github.com/apache/incubator-zeppelin](http://github.com/apache/incubator-zeppelin)
- make modifications inside `zeppelin-web` sub-module

  it is a standard Angular web-application, so you can change anything
- build it

That is basically it.

There are at least 2 companies who are known to successfully follow these steps.

[image: Commercial products based on Zeppelin]

Answer (score 7):

As already mentioned in bzz's answer: it is possible to customise the UI of zeppelin. Here are some more details:

Check out zeppelin source code (e.g. from GitHub https://github.com/apache/zeppelin ). Then:

- To customize the front page (which has a "Welcome to Zeppelin" on it): edit `zeppelin-web/src/app/home/home.html`
- To customise the navbar (which contains a small zeppelin logo and the word zeppelin): edit `zeppelin-web/src/components/navbar/navbar.html`
- To customise the color scheme edit `zeppelin-web/src/app/home/home.css`
  For the navbar color you need to change the entries for navbar-inverse, but many other elements (e.g. interpreter titles) use the same color.

After that you need to rebuild zeppelin `mvn clean install -DskipTests` (note that you may need to force reload in the browser).

Answer (score -1):

See 'how to set a notebook as homepage' in the documentation.
In a notebook you can do whatever formating you like including html.

Comment: I understand we can customize the notebook.  But I am more interested in changing the Zeppelin logo in the blue header bar that appears on every notebook.