# Customized Dashboard using Apache-Zeppelin

Tags: angularjs, visualization, apache-zeppelin, bigdata

I want to implement a dashboard for data analysis based on some interpreters which is supported in zeppelin notebook.
I know how to write a notebook to visualize what I need but that notebook is not good in the BI manager perspective.
Apache-zeppelin capability to convert between chart-types and it's magic keywords are very useful to me.

**Question**: Can I customize Apache-zeppelin UI elements in my website and run the code in the back-end using zeppelin without losing zeppelin UI good features?
I know there is an angularjs in the backend but I don't wan't to go through all d3.js designs ...

Thank You

Comment: zeppelin has good support for js by using a %angular. basically use can use whatever js library you want. check this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37209276/apache-zeppelin-highcharts/38091021#38091021

Comment: Thanks for your comment. That question is about including additional js library in the dashboard but I want to write a hole new website to run codes in the background and show the result in my web page.
I want it to be more customizable than a notebook so I should write it myself :-)

Comment: Then I don't really get what you wanna do. Perhaps you can check the zeppelin code more to find a good way. Or completely use other dashboard.

Comment: @Mohammad Mazraeh, did you figure out a solution for this query. I'm in the same boat as you! But I think this might answer your question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32791384/is-it-possible-to-customize-the-skin-on-zeppelin?rq=1