# Is there a way to increase the font in Apache Zeppelin UI?

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I'm using Ubuntu on a ~15-inch laptop and the Zeppelin UI looks too small:

[image]

Is there a way to somehow increase the UI?

Comment: Simply increase the font? `Ctrl-+`

Comment: @OneCricketeer yes, but it's kind of not right as panels become too large. But I guess that's one way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

1. Download the [source code](https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/), edit the CSS files in `zeppelin/zeppelin-web/src/assets/styles/looknfeel` and compile zeppelin. This is the approach suggested in the answers to [Is it possible to customize the skin on Zeppelin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32791384/is-it-possible-to-customize-the-skin-on-zeppelin)
2. Install a browser extension that allows defining a custom CSS for a page matching a given URL. For example [Stylebot](https://stylebot.dev/). The following stylesheet increases the font size of the input, the output and the cell footer:

```css
.ace_content {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.text.plainTextContent {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.paragraphFooter div {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

[image]